# При попытке по прямой ссылке отредактировать сообщение пользователем с недостаточной репутацией странное сообщение об ошибке

Tags: дефект, правки

К примеру, если попытаться отредактировать пост по [прямой ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9669/edit), появляется сообщение:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

Если же делать всё по кнопке из самого вопроса, то нормальное сообщение об ошибке:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]